# How to create admin theme for Magento2

Tags: admin, theme, magento2

This method works for Magento 1 but not for Magento 2 (version 0.42.0-beta10):
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/admin/using_custom_admin_theme_templates

Answer (score 12):

The Process is quite similar to creating a theme for frontend.

**1.** Create theme.xml in

> `app/design/adminhtml/<yourpackage>/<yourtheme>/theme.xml`

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Magento 2 backend</title>
    <parent>Magento/backend</parent> // set parent theme
 </theme>
```

**2.** Register theme in

> `app/design/adminhtml/<yourpackage>/<yourtheme>/registration.php`

**3.** Enable theme.

```
you can enable frontend theme in admin, but for backend you need to enable the theme through di.xml
```

in  `app/code/Magento/Theme/etc/di.xml`, you can find block of code below. 
add this block of code to your module and change adminhtml to your admin package and theme name.

```
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
       <arguments>
          <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="frontend" xsi:type="string">Magento/luma</item>
            <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">Magento/backend</item>
         </argument>
      </arguments>
    </type>
```

Now you can overwrite something in you admin theme to see whether it works.

Comment: thx, very usefull!

Comment: step 3 improved here http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/120960/23344

Comment: after setup:static-content:deploy nothing is created to my new adminhtml theme, what I'm missing?
I try several config on the composer.json but still no create nothing under static content.
Any suggestion?

Comment: My custom admin theme has no static files generated after running `setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: me too! how do you resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

The theme system has changed a bit in Magento 2 but there are similarities.
First you need to create a theme folder in `app/design/frontend`. The folder structure is similar to the modules structure. You have to have a vendor name (in Magento 1 was called package) and a theme folder .

So create `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme`.
Then you have to declare your theme.
you need to create inside your theme folder a file `theme.xml` with the following content:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Your theme name</title>
    <parent>Magento/blank</parent><!-- or any other parent theme similar to Magento 1.9 -->
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

then create a preview image of your theme inside your theme in the `media` folder(create this also) and call the preview image `preview.jpg` (as declared in the XML above).

Now your theme is set.
If you want to change something from the parent theme all you need to do is copy the file you want to change (layout, template) to your theme from the specific module and do your magic.

For example if you want to change the way that the product view page looks like copy the file `app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` to `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` and change what you need.

[More details about creating a theme can be found here](https://wiki.magento.com/display/MAGE2DOC/How+to+Create+a+Theme).
[I also found a sample theme that you can use as guideline](https://github.com/ubertheme/crafts-magento-2-theme).
You can also install the official sample data and you will get a theme called `luma` where you can see the folder structure.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! But I think I need to translate my bad, sorry.

Comment: I want overiding backend theme (admin theme), not frontend.

Comment: That's no problem. The steps are the same, but instead of `frontend` use `adminhtml` in the folder structure. The principle is the same.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But, I do not understand how to declare the new theme for admin. Is there :"app/code/Magento/Backend/etc/config.xml" ?

Comment: <stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <package>
                    <name>default</name>
                </package>
                <theme>
                    <default>backend</default>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>

Answer (score 2):

In case someone has problems with generating static files for newly created admin theme. In order for magento to generate files for backend theme on setup:static-content:deploy,  `app/design/adminhtml/<yourpackage>/<yourtheme>/web/`
 folder should contain files. Any dummy file would do the job.

Comment: I created a blank main.css in a web folder and I still get no static files created

Comment: @Scott Have you also done all the required steps that Marius suggested in his answer? And how exactly relative path to main.css looks like in your occasion?

Answer (score 0):

To create admin Theme please follow below links, it must be work.

***https://github.com/manishjoy/magento2-admin-theme***

Answer (score 0):

The official guide can be found here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html