# How to extend backend template files in Magento 2

Tags: adminhtml, backend, magento2

I could not find how to extend backend template files in Magento 2, however i have found how to extend frontend template files from [here](http://blog.magestore.com/how-to-create-theme-in-magento-2-part-2/). If I extend the file at `design/adminhtml/Magento/backend` it may override in Magento upgrades version.
So I want to write on `design/adminhtml/vendor/backend` and module specific folders.
However i tried this by placing the required phtml files, but it is not showing from my path, its taking from default magento path.

**C:\xampp\htdocs\NewMagento2\app\design\adminhtml\vendor\backend\Magento_Customer\layout\customer_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="form">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View" name="customer_edit_tab_view" template="tab/view.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="tab_label" xsi:type="string">Customer View</argument>
                    <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="number">10</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View\PersonalInfo" name="personal_info" template="tab/view/personal_info.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**C:\xampp\htdocs\NewMagento2\app\design\adminhtml\Vendor\backend\Magento_Customer\templates\tab\view.phtml**

```
<?php
echo $this->getChildHtml();
```

And if i use templatehints from backend still its showing from magento default i.e. `C:/xampp/htdocs/NewMagento2/app/code//Magento/Customer/view/adminhtml/templates/tab/view.phtml`

Help me in detail on how to extend Magento2 admin template files

Comment: I found @Marius related answer [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59206/how-to-create-admin-theme-for-magento2). But at last not concluded the answer in the comments by Marius

Answer (score 9):

I'm given example here of how to extend the sales order view page. Like this, you can extend any module which one you want. Follow the Below Steps

Step 1) Enable the extension to specify the `config.php` file from the app/etc folder

```
<?php
return array (
  'modules' => 
  array (
        'Learning_RewriteSales' => 1,
  ),
);
```

Step 2) Create `Custom.php` Class in Block

```
<?php
namespace Learning\RewriteSales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;

class Custom extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{

}
```

Step 3) Create `Info.php` file to extend core `Info.php`

```
<?php
namespace Learning\RewriteSales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;

class Info extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info
{

}
```

Step 4) Create `di.xml` file to specify which class you were extended ( Dependency Injection )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info" type="Learning\RewriteSales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info"/>
</config>
```

Step 5) Create `module.xml` file to specify the setup version

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Learning_RewriteSales" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 6) Create `sales_order_view.xml` file from **Learning/RewriteSales/view/layout** folder and write the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">order/view/info.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="order_info">
            <block class="Learning\RewriteSales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Custom" name="sales_order_view_custom" template="order/view/custom.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 7) Create the `Custom.phtml` and `Info.phtml` file from **Learning/RewriteSales/view/layout** and insert below code.

**Custom.phtml**

```
<h1>Hi, I am here!</h1>
```

**Info.phtml**

First Copy the code from **Magento\Sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\view\info.phtml** file and past here after that add one more line

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('sales_order_view_custom');?>
```

Step 8) Finally clean the cache and see your custom code Sales Order View Page.

It's working for me. If you have any queries let me know?

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! What if I want to do something even simpler than this: what if I just want to override a style in `magento2\vendor\magento\theme-adminhtml-backend\web\css\source\forms\_controls.less`? I hope you can answer [my question that I posted separately](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121116/magento-2-how-to-override-adminhtml-css).

Comment: https://ranasohel.me/2015/10/02/how-to-overwrite-sales-view-order-phtml-file-in-magento2/

Answer (score 0):

And this is `my .js` file code.

```
defaults: {
                template: 'Magento_SamplePaymentGateway/payment/form',
                medicaidId: '',
                dateOfBirth: '',
            },

            initObservable: function () {
                this._super()
                    .observe('medicaidId'); 
                this._super()
                    .observe('dateOfBirth');
                return this;
            },

            getCode: function() {
                return 'sample_gateway';
            },

            getData: function() {

                return {
                    'method': this.item.method,
                    "additional_data":{
                        'medicaid_id': this.medicaidId(),
                        'do_birth': this.dateOfBirth()                                              
                        }
                };

            },
```

Answer (score 0):

And this is my Observer

```
protected $additionalInformationList = [
        'medicaid_id', 'do_birth'        
    ];
public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $data = $this->readDataArgument($observer);
        $additionalData = $data->getData(PaymentInterface::KEY_ADDITIONAL_DATA);
        //$this->_logger->log(100,print_r($additionalData,true));
        if (!is_array($additionalData)) {

            return;
        }
        $paymentInfo = $this->readPaymentModelArgument($observer);
        //$this->_logger->log(100,print_r($paymentInfo,true));

        foreach ($this->additionalInformationList as $additionalInformationKey) {
            if (isset($additionalData[$additionalInformationKey])) {
                $paymentInfo->setAdditionalInformation(
                    $additionalInformationKey,
                    $additionalData[$additionalInformationKey]
                );
            }
        }
}
```