# How to override adminhtml phtml files in magento2

Tags: adminhtml, overrides, magento2

How to override adminhtml phtml files in magento2?

I want to place a custom text in customer edit page **welcome to magento2**.
For this I have created a theme and placed

`app\design\adminhtml\Vendor\backend\Magento_Customer\templates\tab\view.phtml`

```
<h1>WELCOME TO MAGENTO2</h1>
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
```

but it's not working, when I place the same in 
`app\code\Magento\Customer\view\adminhtml\templates\tab\view.phtml`
then it's working.

Comment: Do you enable custom theme for adminhtml aria?

Comment: did you get that working?

Comment: @PhilippSander for adminhtml template files we have to create seperate theme for admin and edit template files same as front end module based structure

Comment: thanks! already solved it myself with a different approach

Comment: @PhilippSander, can you post here what was your different approach ?

Comment: If you have solved, you should share how you solved it. That's how a community works.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76434/how-to-extend-backend-template-files-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

adminhtml phtml file can be override as steps below

STEP 1: Add page layout XML in custom module.

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name='order_totals'>
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name='template' translate="true" xsi:type='string'>[Vendor]_[Module]::order/totals.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

STEP 2: Put template file on below path

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/templates/order/totals.phtml

```
Write custom code with existing content!!!
```

STEP 3: Depending on your cache settings you may need to clear your cache `php bin/magento cache:clear`

Hope it will work for you :)

Answer (score -3):

I created a new module and copied the file to

`app/code/[vendor]/[module]/view/adminhtml/templates/tab/view.phtml`

it works.

Comment: This will not work.