# How to overwrite a template via module in Magento2

Tags: blocks, template, magento2, frontend

I am creating a module and want to overwrite the template `app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/options.phtml`.

Is this possible in a module (not a theme)

Unfortunately it does not seem super-easy to change the module name via layout XML, as this is set hard-coded in https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/Options.php#L21

Comment: Please refer this link for the answer
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76434/how-to-extend-backend-template-files-in-magento-2

Comment: Please refer this link for answer
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76434/how-to-extend-backend-template-files-in-magento-2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add layout folder of you module file 
[Vendor]/[ModuleName]/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_options.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="admin.product.options">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="template" xsd:type="string">[Vendor]/[ModuleName]::product_options.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

Also need add to module xml this line, to load you layouts after catalog

```
<sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
</sequence>
```

Comment: Where did you get the name `admin.product.options` from?

Comment: Just search \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options by layout files and find out declaration in Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_options.xml

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Vendor_ModuleName::product_options.phtml`?

Comment: Yes, thank for point

Comment: This solution only works, if the original template was set in the Block.php file. If the original template is set on the layout.xml, this solution will not work. A better approach is to always use `<action method="setTemplate">` instead of `<arguments>`. This solution works in all cases.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create corresponding layout file in your module:

> [Vendor]/[ModuleName]/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_options.xml

2. Set your custom template configuration

> ```
> <layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
>     <referenceBlock name="admin.product.options">
>         <action method="setTemplate">
>             <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">[Vendor]_[ModuleName]::product_options.phtml</argument>
>         </action>
>     </referenceBlock>
> </layout>
> ```

NOTE: it is very important to use `<action method="setTemplate">` instead of `<arguments>`. `<arguments>` will only work if the block does not have another template specified on the xml declaration. In any other case, you need `<action method="setTemplate">` to override the existing template. It is better to use `<action method="setTemplate">` because it always works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can overwrite template files from app/code of your custom module. However, do keep in mind that in Magento's inheritance concept, files (templates, layouts, static files) from app/design overwrite the same in app/code. Just as child theme overwrites parent theme.

So, I consider it best to create a custom theme for your custom module and add all your phtml, xml, css, js, font and image files there in app/design.