# how to override $_template variable through di.xml

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, template, di

I am trying to update the template through di.xml in the admin section. I want to change the template of Admin > Catalog > bundle > option template.

I tried the below code, but it's not working for me.

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/Module.xsd">
    <module name="Rmsundar_Bundle" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Bundle"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Bundle\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Bundle\Option">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Rmsundar_Bundle::product/edit/bundle/option.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. If we use preference we can override the `_construct` method, in that we can set the template.

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Bundle\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Bundle\Option" type="Rmsundar\Bundle\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Bundle\Option" /> 
</config>
```

**Option.php**

```
<?php

namespace Rmsundar\Bundle\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Bundle;

class Option extends \Magento\Bundle\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Bundle\Option
{
    protected $_template = 'Rmsundar_Bundle::product/edit/bundle/option.phtml';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Bundle\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Bundle\Option">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="data"  xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Rmsundar_Bundle::product/edit/bundle/option.phtml</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: above code is not working

Comment: This work only if the layout does not overwrite the arguments. Can you describe what you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to change the template file of an block `\Magento\Bundle\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Bundle\Option`

Comment: Why do not use layout for this?

Comment: can you guide me or give some example

Comment: see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88612/how-to-overwrite-a-template-via-module-in-magento2

Comment: @KAndy, Its working for my case Magento\Email\Block\Adminhtml\Template\Edit override template files. +1