# How to change the search results page?

Tags: magento2

Just after in need of a bit of help / advice on coding my magento 2 site! Basically I want to change parts of the catalog search results page by removing 2 lines of text that is automatically generated, or edit them to say my own message! If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great! Please see the image below for the lines I want to remove/edit!

Thanks.

[image: Lines to be removed marked by red arrows!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines can be found in the following template:

`vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/advanced/result.phtml`

You'll have to rewrite this template to remove them, or you can just add your own translation of the following lines to replace them with your own message:

`<strong>%1 item</strong> were found using the following search criteria`

and

`Don't see what you're looking for?`

If you want to rewrite this template, check [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88612/how-to-overwrite-a-template-via-module-in-magento2).

Comment: I have changed this line as you suggested however it is still showing the old message. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you flushed your cache completely?