# Magento 2 Fail to override template

Tags: magento2, template, overrides

I want to override the `register.phtml` in `Magento_Customer` module. But the setTemplate method fails to override the original `register.phtml` because the `register.phtml` was overridden in `Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes`

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_ModuleName::form/register.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
```

In this case, how can I replace the template, or how can I insert a set of radio button into that template? since my intention is to add radio button to the template. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The action node is deprecated in magento 2. You should change your xml to this

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_ModuleName::form/register.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

If you want to override a template that a magento 2 core module is already overriding, you need to override that override. To do this you should add the module that is already doing the override as a sequence in your module.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_module" setup_version="100.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

No flush your cache and reload your page and you should see your template getting loaded.

**UPDATE:**
The devdocs state that "[The `<action>` instruction is deprecated.](http://goo.gl/laVP35)" but in all cases I have encountered, the  instruction is the only method that can successfully override a template. This [github issue](https://goo.gl/diV0Fx) says this is currently a bug.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it does not work.

Comment: Ricky / for others' reference: Nathan is incorrect about `<action method="...">` being deprecated. The layout XML given in the question should be exactly correct. He is correct about the sequence tag, though; that should ensure that your XML gets parsed after the other module(s) you reference.

Comment: @RyanH. I was going off of the M2 Dev Doc's (http://goo.gl/laVP35) which states "The `<action>` instruction is deprecated." Unfortunately there is a bug with the <arguments> tag (https://goo.gl/diV0Fx) preventing my code above from working properly. For now it is acceptable to use action as it is the only method that works for overriding a template in layout xml at the moment. I will update my original post to make note of this fact.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Enable the extension to specify config.php file from app/etc folder

```
    <?php
    return array (
      'modules' => 
      array (
            'Learning_RewriteSales' => 1,
      ),
    );
```

Step 2) Create Custom.php Class in Block

```
    <?php
    namespace Learning\RewriteSales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;

    class Custom extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
    {

    }
```

Step 3) Create Info.php file to extend core Info.php

```
    <?php
    namespace Learning\RewriteSales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;

    class Info extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info
    {

    }
```

Step 4) Create di.xml file to specify which class you where extended ( Dependency Injection )

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
       <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info" type="Learning\RewriteSales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info"/>
      </config>
```

Step 5) Create a module.XML file to specify the setup version

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
          <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
               <module name="Learning_RewriteSales" setup_version="2.0.0">
                      <sequence>
               <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
                      </sequence>
               </module>
          </config>
```

Step 6) Create sales_order_view.xml file from Learning/RewriteSales/view/layout folder and write the below code

```
          <?xml version="1.0"?>
                <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
                     <body>
                         <referenceBlock name="order_info">
                               <action method="setTemplate">
                                   <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">order/view/info.phtml</argument>
                               </action>
                        </referenceBlock>
                        <referenceBlock name="order_info">
                              <block class="Learning\RewriteSales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Custom" name="sales_order_view_custom" template="order/view/custom.phtml" />
                        </referenceBlock>
                     </body>
                  </page>
```

Step 7) Create the Custom.phtml and Info.phtml file from Learning/RewriteSales/view/layout and insert below code.

Custom.phtml

```
        <h1>Hi, I am here!</h1>
```

Info.phtml

First Copy the code from Magento\Sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\view\info.phtml file and past here after that add one more line

```
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('sales_order_view_custom');?>
```

Step 8) Finally clean the cache and to see your custom code Sales Order View Page.
reference: [How to extend backend template files in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76434/how-to-extend-backend-template-files-in-magento-2)