# Edit backend in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, overrides, backend

I've been trying to edit my backend, but without any results, does anyone know how, step by step? 
I've already try [How to extend backend template files in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76434/how-to-extend-backend-template-files-in-magento-2)

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but please any help would do.
Thanks!

PS. I'm looking for editing styles, BTW.

Comment: Please be more specific, are you editing the admin login page, what do you have and what are you trying to do?  What version of Magento are you using?

Comment: Im trying to do styles in all backend, by extending a less or overriding the styles in Magento 2. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes - it is possible.  I don't have time to write a guide for you for a couple of more days.  You need to look in the ```app/design/adminhtml``` folder.  It might be empty, but you would place the same filename of the admin files you are wishing to update styles on.

Comment: well, i was able to edit the backend styles, the way i did it was following the steps i mentioned before, then cleaning cache, erase static files, upgrade and deploy. Only then the changes were applied.
The problem was passing the changes production side, it won't apply...
This is my report for now. If anyone knows something about that, let me know.

Comment: Cool, for Magneto 2 deployment to a production enabled server I had to take some specific steps.  Moni, the only way I've consistently been able to apply styles to production has been 1) rm -r pub/static 2) rm -r var/cache/ 3) rm -r var/view_preprocessed/ 4) deploy static content command here (mine is custom) 5) Clear browser cache with settings or extension.  -  Please use -r and not -rf to practice safe computing.  Be very careful with the var as it's easy to mistype /var.  I recommend create a script for you personally.

Comment: Magento 2 docs can promise all they want that deploying to server just requires the static content deployment command or to remove view preprocessed, but I've had hit or miss results with the caching.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227192/variationmatrix-error-with-product-at-magento-2-backend please help me out of it.Thanks in advance