# Where I need to create backend admin theme(vendor_name) in magento 2?

Tags: adminhtml, theme, magento2-dev-beta

I'm Getting Started in Magento 2. Here I created theme From `app\design\frontend\Magento\<vendor_name>\<vendorname_modulename>` it's working fine (under Vendor modules showing store front).

And I have created Adminhtml theme from `app\design\adminhtml\<vendor_name>\<backend>\<vendorname_modulename>` it's not working (under vendor modules from admin area).

**Here I have a question.**

**Where I need to create backend admin Vendor_Theme?**

Need to Create Vendor_Theme inside `app\design\adminhtml\Magento\<backend>\<vendor_name>\<vendorname_modulename>`?

or

Need to Create Vendor_Theme inside `app\design\adminhtml\<vendor_name>\<backend>\<vendorname_modulename>`?

**Please suggest me Where I need to create backend admin theme in magento 2??**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96559/41517

Step 3 on the above solution has been improved here 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/120960/41517