# Magento 2 - Load custom javascript with requirejs

Tags: magento2, javascript, adminhtml, theme

**The Problem**

I want to use custom JavaScript in `Products/Inventory/Catalog` page to modify the "Add Product" button behavior and hide some fields in product edit form (where the SKU, weight, name, qty, etc, of a product, is shown) as well.

**What I've Done**

For that reason, I've created an admin theme as described in this question: [How to create admin theme for Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59206/how-to-create-admin-theme-for-magento2)

The admin theme was successfully created and all static content was generated without problems. After that, I tried to load my custom js in all admin pages by doing the following:

In `design/adminhtml/myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/adminhtml/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="js/customAdmin"/>        
    </head>
</page>
```

In folder `design/adminhtml/myvendor/mytheme/web/js/` is `customAdmin.js`

And in `design/adminhtml/myvendor/mytheme/web/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    "shim": {
        "customAdmin": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        }
    },
    "paths": {
        "customAdmin": "js/customAdmin"
    }
};
```

Nonetheless, the js file is not loaded on any admin page.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: would you be able to share what your customAdmin.js file looks like or the structure of it? I am having the same problems

Comment: @mikebertiean This is my customAdmin.js: `require(
 [
  'jquery'
 ], function($){

        function disableSKU(){
            // Disable SKU
        }

        setTimeout(disableSKU, 10000);
 
 }
);` What are the problems you're having?

Comment: thank you, i was wondering about the structure of what the js file needs to look like more then anything. cheers for that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See what is below

requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            customAdmin: 'Namespace_Modulename/js/customAdmin'
        }
    },
    deps: ["jquery"]
};
```

or use in phtml:

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'Namespace_Modulename/js/customAdmin'],
    function ($) {
        return ...;
    }
);
</script>
```

---

or use requirejs-config.js and phtml:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            customAdmin: 'Namespace_Modulename/js/customAdmin'
        }
    }
};
```

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'customAdmin'],
    function ($) {
        return ...;
    }
);
</script>
```

Comment: sorry for the late response. This solved my problem, thank you.