# Magento 2 : add custom JavaScript to CMS page create/edit in admin

Tags: admin, javascript, adminhtml, requirejs

I would like to add some custom JavaScript to the CMS page create/edit pages in Magento 2 admin. So basically when you want to create a new page or edit an existing one, it should load some JavaScript preferably before body closing tag.

How would I go about doing this?
I've already looked at the following posts:

- [Adding custom CSS to admin backend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37695251/6189764) (thought it might similarly for js)
- [How to add custom css for adminhtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/137442/46880) (same as previous)
- http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_and_requirejs/
- [Magento 2 override amin js file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39015238/6189764)
- [Unable to run custom js to admin backend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/177641/46880)

The one by Alan Storm did work, but it loaded my js on all admin pages, but that's not the idea, I just want to load my js for the CMS page create and edit pages.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try following way:

**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/cms_page_edit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Cms\Custom" name="info" before="before.body.end" template="Vendor_Module::cms/custom.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Vendor/Module/Block/Cms/Custom.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Cms;

class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

}
```

**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/cms/custom.phtml**

```
Custom Block
<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function($){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log('here')
        } );
    })
</script>
```

Comment: There's still a problem, the page seems to be rendered via Ajax I think, so whenever I try to log a value from one of the inputs from 'cms_page_form.xml' I get an undefined. How do I make it load after all form fields have rendered?

Comment: So after some more messing around, I found it is not Ajax, the fields just don't get renered until you click the parent fieldset (open the fieldset). That makes things a bit difficult. I'm still trying to figure out how to go about this.

Comment: What you actually want? This code added custom block as well as template with JS.

Comment: I think I found out what happens: apparently  Magento 2 load all "fieldsets" on the admin pages, but doesn't load the underlying fields until clicked on the fieldset, that's why my js couldn't find the values, because they were not yet set.
Now I'm checking if they are already set and if not, listen on the openining of the fieldset before trying again.
What I want to do is be able to link CMS pages to other pages (which I got working), but exclude the current page from the list of selectable pages to link to.

Comment: Try to set timeout for 5sec, then you can able to catch field.

Comment: I did, but the fields only get rendered after opening its corresponding fieldset, so just a timeout didn't cut it. I had to set a timeout for rendering the fieldsets and after they were set, set a listener for opening a specific fieldset to allow getting the data from the desired fields.

Comment: Hi Nico, how to open the fieldset here with js? I am trying to add some js code for the cms form but its not there yet. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After quite a lot of messing around with it, I've finally found a solution quite similar to what @SohelRana suggested, except I didn't create my own block, but used Magento's default template block instead.

Basically what I did was create two layout rewrites: **app/code/Vender/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/cms_page_edit.xml** and **…/cms_page_new.xml** with both the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::js.phtml" name="custom_cms_js"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

After that I created the following file **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/js.phtml** with the following content:

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log('This is it, success!');
        });
    })
</script>
```