# Backend page title change Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

How can i change the default title of back-end pages. On which block / page file i need to edit. I am new Magento, so if you could explain it from scratch , it would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via xml. You will need to create an admin theme first.

[How to create admin theme for Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59206/how-to-create-admin-theme-for-magento2)

This will help you initally set up the theme ready to make a few changes to layouts.

Then find the location of the xml for for that page. This can normally be done by looking at the admin url.

**Catalog Product Grid Example**

For the url **admin/catalog/product/index** the original file for layout could be found within `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/catalog_product_index.xml`. I used the first part of the url to determine the module. Then looked within `view/adminhtml` folder for layout files for this module. The file should match the url like above from after your adminpath, so **catalog/product/index** will be `catalog_product_view.xml`.

This file should be left alone however can be overridden within your new admin theme. Create the following file:

> app/code/design/adminhtml/vendor/admintheme/Magento_Catalog/view/template/catalog_product_view.xml

This will be different for each module in this example module-catalog is overidden by files within Magento_Catalog in your custom admin theme and module-sales-inventory would be Magento_SalesInventory.

So to change the title for this page add this xml to your custom `catalog_product_view.xml` within new theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="page.title">
  <action method="setPageTitle">
    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">New Title</argument>
 </action>
</referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Depending on which mode your in you may need to flush cache, deploy static content ect. Your changes should then be live on your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the title via your block with this function:

```
public function _prepareLayout()
{
   //set page title
   $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('New title'));

   return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```